# childrens ID's are getting duplicate under chakra UI MENU component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, duplicates, chakra-ui

MenuBUTTONS id is getting duplicate in chakra Menu component.

i am new to chakra. i am trying to create sidebar using chakra MENU component. i have used MenuButton's as shown below. generated code is having duplicate button id's. also when user clicking on one button then all the buttons are becoming active state.

```
<Menu>
  <MenuButton>
    <Flex>
      menubtn
    </Flex>
  </MenuButton>
  <MenuButton>
    <Flex>
      menubtn
    </Flex>
  </MenuButton>
  <MenuButton>
    <Flex>
      menubtn
    </Flex>
  </MenuButton>
  <MenuButton>
    <Flex>
      menubtn
    </Flex>
  </MenuButton>
</Menu>
```

Generated HTML.

```
<button id="menu-button-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-controls="menu-list-2" class="chakra-menu__menu-button css-er1y57">content</button>
<button id="menu-button-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-controls="menu-list-2" class="chakra-menu__menu-button css-er1y57">content</button>
<button id="menu-button-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-controls="menu-list-2" class="chakra-menu__menu-button css-er1y57">content</button>
<button id="menu-button-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-controls="menu-list-2" class="chakra-menu__menu-button css-er1y57">content</button>
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MenuItem` and pass some unique id or index as key

```
         <MenuButton>
            <MenuItem onClick={() => foo()} key={something.id}>
               <Flex>
                  menubtn
               </Flex>
            </MenuItem>
         </MenuButton>
```